# make two thread in two different core in C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, cpu-cores

I read some articles about this problem. The case seems to be not easy. I want to create two different threads in two cores. The articles that I read were too complicated. I even couldn't create a simple thread based on those articles. On the other hand, I need to understand how many cores a computer has to make available as a choice for using both cores or just creating threads on one core. I want to do them on Windows.
Any help would be highly welcome

p.s: I am not that pro on C++. So please if it is possible guide me with easier ways.

Comment: Could you state which OS or thread libraries you are considering?  If you haven't decided you could go with boost threads or posix which are two popular choices.

Comment: @MartyE: I want to code in windows. anyway I am open to any library suggestion

Comment: gotcha (I now see that in the title).  For the native windows way, try out jerrycoffin's answer and if it works accept it.  Other option would be to try boost threads though it doesn't seem recommended

Comment: If you create two threads, and the two threads are actually in the running state, and there are at least two cores free, then you will get what you want anyway - you don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though it's generally a lousy idea (the thread scheduler *usually* does a better job on its own), the basic idea would be:

```
HANDLE thread_a = CreateThread(/* ... */);
HANDLE thread_b = CreateThread(/* ... */);

SetThreadAffinityMask(thread_a, 1 << 0);
SetThreadAffinityMask(thread_b, 1 << 1);
```

Note that the `1<<0` and `1<<1` could just as easily be written as `1` and `2` respectively -- I was just trying to make explicit the fact that each bit position represents a processor.

Comment: thank you. which header file should I use for using these tow? and is there a way to understand how many core is available in pc. is there any tutorial for createthread function? how can I start it? or give it the function that I want to make it a process?

Comment: @Masoud: Both are in `<windows.h>` at least if memory serves. Not sure about tutorials, but you might want to look it up on MSDN. [GetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683213.aspx) will give you as mask showing the available processors.

Comment: @Masoud - while Jerry's answer is fine, maybe you should do some more research and/or get some more multithreaded experience before attempting any such 'optimizations'.  I'm getting the feeling that, whatever you are trying to do, with your level of experience, you will not succeed :(

Comment: @JerryCoffin : Thanks a lot jerry. If there was any available tutorial please tell me.

Comment: @MartinJames : I should try Martin. ;) I really need it. if you know a good tutorial please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

For posix, check out `pthread_getaffinity_np` and `pthread_setaffinity_np`

Comment: thanks martyE. is posix a wrapper? is there any good and simple tutorial about it?